# How to count time absolutely, not on a 24 hour clock

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to find out the total runtime of a group of videos. I have a table of times for each episode in Excel, formatted in the Time format, e.g.

```
1 | 00:28:04
2 | 00:33:05
3 | 00:27:43
```

The problem is, the Time counter operates on a 24 hour clock, so when I sum everything, it loops.

What I want to happen:

```
23:59:59 +
00:00:02 =
24:00:01
```

What actually happens:

```
23:59:59 +
00:00:02 =
00:00:01
```

How can I format the cell displaying the total times such that it displays an absolute time value, not a 24-hour clock format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use square brackets around the hours, e.g. Custom format as follows:

> [hh]:mm:ss

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I need it to do! I'll accept it in 9 minutes.

Comment: Sorry, that was a long 9 minutes. The internet is dark and full of distractions.